# Skip cognito hosted ui and use custom ui for social login

Tags: amazon-cognito, google-signin

I am trying to bypass Cognito's hosted UI and have my custom UI for social login, I used Amplify for creating user with username and password, but for user creation using social login documentation says to use Cognito Hosted UI, is there a way to create user pool without using Cognito's Hosted UI.

I tried to build my own but after receiving code from google on redirect I don't know how to create data in Cognito's user pool

Comment: I have found a way to implement it, you need to pass the provider as Google or Facebook in amplify login

Comment: <button onClick={() => Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google })}>Open Google</button>